# How can I integrate Google Classroom API with Unity so that students can submit quiz answers through my game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-classroom

I am trying to integrate Google Classroom API into my Unity game so that students can submit their results through my game to their teacher in the form of Quiz/Assignments. I have OAuth working and I am able to get their ID Token as well. Is there any tool or SDK that can help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is [not yet supported](https://developers.google.com/classroom/faq#can_i_answer_questions_in_the_api).

An alternative would be to add rows to a spreadsheet instead and then later on process that to get the quiz score. However this would be outside of your Google Classroom setup.

Hope this helps you!